# Large file uploads with Java applet

Tags: java, file-upload, applet

I've been tasked with implementing large (2gb+) file uploads via a web browser. After evaluating various technologies, java applets seem to be the way forward (only one's which provide proper access to the local disk). I was wondering if anyone can recommend a 3rd party file upload app we can use as a base? requirements are

- Decent UI, ideally we want something similar to facebooks photo uploader
- Can handle large (2gb+) files
- Resumable uploads
- We beed the source to extend it to our needs (dont mind paying extra)

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for [JUpload](http://jupload.sourceforge.net/).

Update: not sure if it has as nice of UI as you're hoping, but unless you want to build a custom solution like I have it's your best option.

Answer (score 2):

Just a tip, maybe it is obvious, i don't know :P

It is nice to send the big file in chunks like 2mb, and on the server side you just append the bytes to the target file. The server knows what bytes it needs, and if a upload is aborted and continued later, the server can just send a message about from what bytes to start uploading the file again. Then we get resumability (is it a word? :P) and safety of large HTTP-uploads (since, in fact, we are sending many smuller uploads, and each upload is checked to be of the correct size on the server).

We wrote an implementation like this once with a Java-applet as the client and PHP on the server, I'll see if I can dig it out as a reference for you :p

Comment: I'm interested. What Java applet did you use here? Jupload does something like what you describe.

Comment: I wrote my own :) It's really not that complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a solution : from experience you may bump into the following issues:

- problems when uploading over HTTPs
- problems uploading through proxies

Just wanted to make you aware of these two cases, for you to test when evaluating a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hope, you will get solutions for your prob over here.. http://jupload.sourceforge.net/